# Deployer - no tty present and no askpass program specified - How to deploy with Deployer

Tags: php, git, laravel, ssh, deployment

I have trouble deploying with [Deployer 4.0.2](https://deployer.org) and I am in need for help of somebody more experienced than me in this.

I want to deploy a repository of mine to a `Ubuntu 16.04` server.

I am using [laravel homestead](https://github.com/laravel/homestead) as a development environment, where I also installed deployer. From there I ssh into my remote server.

I was able to deploy my code with the `root` user, until I hit a `RuntimeException`that aborted my deployment.

```
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
```

That made me create another user called `george`, whom I gave superuser rights. I copied my public key from my local machine to a newly generated `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, that gave me permission to access the server via ssh.

Yet when I run `dep deploy` with the new user:

```
server('production', '138.68.99.157')
    ->user('george')
    ->identityFile()
    ->set('deploy_path', '/var/www/test');
```

I get another `RuntimeException`:

```
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Now it looks like the new user `george` cannot access the `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`key. So I copy them from the root folder into my home folder and also add the public key in the Github SSH settings.

```
cp root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub home/george/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
cp root/.ssh/id_rsa home/george/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Only to get the same error as before.

In the end I had to add github to my list of authorized hosts:

```
ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Only to get the next `RuntimeException`

```
[RuntimeException]
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

I managed to comment this code in the `deploy.php`

```
// desc('Restart PHP-FPM service');
// task('php-fpm:restart', function () {
//     // The user must have rights for restart service
//     // /etc/sudoers: username ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/systemctl restart php-fpm.service
//     run('sudo systemctl restart php-fpm.service');
// });
// after('deploy:symlink', 'php-fpm:restart');
```

to get the deployment process finally done, and now I ask myself, if the `restart` of php-fpm is really necessary, for me to continue debugging this deployment tool? Or can I live without it?

And if I need it, can somebody help me understand what I need it for? And maybe as a luxury also provide the solution to the RuntimeException?

Comment: I assume that the php-fpm restart is used to clear the opcache. But there are better solutions (see https://deployer.org/recipes/cachetool.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
->identityFile('~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub', '~/.ssh/id_rsa', 'pass phrase')
```

It works great for me - no need for an askpass program.
It helps to be explicit in my experience.

As for your phpfm restart task .. I haven't seen that before. Shouldn't be needed. :)

EDIT:

That you provide a password is probably a good sign that you ought to refactor your Deployer code a bit if you keep it under source control.

I am loading site specific data from a YAML file - which I am **not** submitting to source control.

The first bit of my `stage.yml` :

```
# Site Configuration
# -------------
prod_1:
    host: hostname
    user: username
    identity_file:
        public_key: /home/user/.ssh/key.pub
        private_key: /home/user/.ssh/key
        password: "password"
    stage: production
    repository: https://github.com/user/repository.git
    deploy_path: /var/www
    app:
        debug: false
        stage: 'prod'
```

And then, in my `deploy.php` :

```
if (!file_exists (__DIR__ . '/deployer/stage/servers.yml')) {
  die('Please create "' . __DIR__ . '/deployer/stage/servers.yml" before continuing.' . "\n");
}
serverList(__DIR__ . '/deployer/stage/servers.yml');
set('repository', '{{repository}}');

set('default_stage', 'production');
```

Notice that, when you use `serverList`, it replaces your server setup in `deploy.php`